# How to adjust biblography style using biblatex package?

Tags: biblatex, ieee-style

I'm using biblatex package with IEEE style:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=IEEE,natbib=true, sorting=none, url=true, doi=true,hyperref=true]{biblatex}***
```

The output is like:

> V. Ruiz-Albacete, P. Tome-Gonzalez, F. Alonso-Fernandez, J. Galbally, J. Fierrez, and J. OrtegaGarcia, “Direct attacks using fake images in iris verification”, in Biometrics and Identity Management, T. M. Schouten B., Juul N.C., Drygajlo A.,Ed.,vol. 5372,Springer Berlin Heidelberg,2008, pp. 181–190.

I'd like it to be

> V. Ruiz-Albacete, P. Tome-Gonzalez, F. Alonso-Fernandez, J. Galbally, J. Fierrez, and J. OrtegaGarcia, “Direct attacks using fake images in iris verification”, In: T. M. Schouten B., Juul N.C., Drygajlo A., (Eds.), Biometrics and Identity Management, Springer Berlin Heidelberg,
>   vol. 5372, pp. 181–190, 2008.

Comment: Is the `IEEE` style different to `ieee` style? I don't get your output with first output with `ieee` style and I can't find `IEEE` style. Can you provide a complete [MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography) please?

Comment: It's not too difficult to modify the `ieee` style to give the output you want. But it does require quite a few changes. And it's not clear how these changes might affect other entry types than `@inbook` from your question.

Comment: IEEE is the same as ieee.
This problem appears with springer puplications only.
IEEE puplications have no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to modify the `inbook` driver to match your desired output. Note that this will put `volume` and `pages` between `publisher` and `date` for other entry types too, which you may not want. Anyway, perhaps it will get you started for further changes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inbook{Ruiz-Albacete2008,
  author = {Ruiz-Albacete, Virginia and Tome-Gonzalez, Pedro and Alonso-Fernandez, Fernando and Galbally, Javier and Fierrez, Julian and Ortega-Garcia, Javier},
  editor = {Schouten, Ben and Juul, Niels Christian and Drygajlo, Andrzej and Tistarelli, Massimo},
  title = {Direct Attacks Using Fake Images in Iris Verification},
  booktitle = {Biometrics and Identity Management},
  volume = {5372},
  date = {2008},
  publisher = {Springer Berlin Heidelberg},
  pages = {181-190},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[style=ieee,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
% put colon after In:
\renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\addcolon\space}
% use comma between fields
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
% put Eds. in parentheses 
\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
% swap editor and book title
\xpatchbibdriver{inbook}
  {\usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  {\usebibmacro{byeditor+others}
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}}
  {}
  {}
% remove a hard coded period
\xpatchbibdriver{inbook}
  {\setunit{\adddot\addspace}}
  {\newunit}
  {}
  {}
% use capital In
\xpatchbibmacro{in:}
  {\bibstring}
  {\bibsentence\bibstring}
  {}
  {}
% put volume and pages before date
\xpatchbibmacro{publisher+location+date}
  {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
   \usebibmacro{date}}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{volume+part}%
   \renewbibmacro{volume+part}{}%
   \newunit
   \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
   \renewbibmacro*{chapter+pages}{}%
   \newunit
   \usebibmacro{date}}
  {}
  {}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]